# unable to delete row from Mysql using nodeJs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I had created a pet shop web app using nodeJS and MySql. I am able to insert pets info in data successfully but I am not able to delete pets using pet_id. I am getting following error

> [
> code: 'ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE',
> errno: 1292,
> sqlMessage: "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'pa04'",
> sqlState: '22007',
> index: 0,
> sql: "DELETE FROM pets WHERE pet_id=`pet_id` = 'pa04'"
> ] .

But when I give pet_id as Integer i.e; 5 nothing happens, even error didn't come.I had tried putting a Ajax code in my ejs but I failed. Please help me.
Thanks in advance :)

```
const { count } = require('console');
var express = require('express');
var mysql=require('mysql');
const { createConnection } = require('net');
var app = express();
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');

app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname +"/public"))

var connection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    database:'mini_project',
    password:'password'
});


app.get("/animals", function(req, res){
    var q="select animals.pet_id,pet_category,breed,weight,age,height,fur,cost from animals join pets on animals.pet_id= pets.pet_id";
    connection.query(q,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render("dogs_home",{data:results});
    
    });
});



app.get("/birds", function(req, res){
    var q="select birds.pet_id,type,noise,cost from birds join pets on birds.pet_id= pets.pet_id";
        connection.query(q,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render("birds_home",{data:results});
    });
});


app.get("/",function(req,res){
        res.render("home");

});


app.get("/accessories", function(req, res){
    var q="select * from pet_products";
    connection.query(q,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render("accessories",{data:results});
    
    });
});


app.get("/sales", function(req, res){
    var q="select * from sales_details";
    connection.query(q,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render("sales",{data:results});
    
    });
});


app.get("/customers", function(req, res){
    var q="select * from customer";
    connection.query(q,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render("customer",{data:results});
    
    });
});

app.get("/ani_add", function(req, res){
 
        res.render("ani_add");
    
});

app.get("/animal_id_add", function(req, res){
 
    res.render("animal_id_add");

});



app.post("/register_dogs",function(req,res){
    var dog={pet_id:req.body.pet_id,
             breed:req.body.breed,
             weight:req.body.weight,
             height:req.body.height,
             age:req.body.age,
             fur:req.body.fur};
    var q="insert into animals set ?"
    connection.query(q,dog,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.redirect("/animals");
});

});

app.post("/register_dogs_id",function(req,res){
    var dog={pet_id:req.body.pet_id,
             pet_category:req.body.pet_category,
             cost:req.body.cost};
    var q="insert into pets set ?"
    connection.query(q,dog,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.redirect("/ani_add");
});

});

//route for delete data
app.post('/delete',(req, res) => {
    let q = "DELETE FROM pets WHERE pet_id=?";
    let dog={pet_id:req.body.pet_id};
    connection.query(q,dog,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.redirect("/animals");
});

});
```

```
******** dogs_home.ejs *******

<html>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css">
  <body>
    <table id="table"  border="1%" width="99.5%"
           style="background-color: rgba(169, 169, 169, 0.726)"
           >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>pet id</th>
                <th>Pet Category</th>
                <th>Breed</th>
                <th>Weight(Kgs)</th>
                <th>Age(Yrs)</th>
                <th>Height(Inchs)</th>
                <th>Fur</th>
                <th>cost</th>


            </tr>
        </thead>
         <tbody>

         <% data.forEach(function (user) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= user.pet_id %></td>
                <td><%= user.pet_category %></td>
                <td><%= user.breed %></td>
                <td><%= user.weight %></td>
                <td><%= user.age %></td>
                <td><%= user.height %></td>
                <td><%= user.fur %></td>
                <td><%= user.cost %></td>



            </tr>
         <% }) %>


         </tbody>
    </table>

<div>
    <a href="/animal_id_add"><button>Add new animal</button></a>
</div>

    <div>
        <form action="/delete" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="form" name="pet_id" placeholder="Pet Id">
        <button>DELETE</button>
    </form>
    </div>

</body>

</html>


******* animal_id_add.ejs *******
<html><body>
    <div>
        <form method="POST" action='/register_dogs_id'>

        <input type="text" class="form" name="pet_id" placeholder="Pet Id">
        <input type="text" class="form" name="pet_category" placeholder="pet_category">
        <input type="text" class="form" name="cost" placeholder="cost">
        <button type="submit">Add</button>

    </form>



    </div>

</body></html>


******* ani_add.ejs ********
<html>
    <body>
        

        <div>
            <form method="POST" action='/register_dogs'>


                <input type="text" class="form" name="pet_id" placeholder="Pet Id">
                <input type="text" class="form" name="breed" placeholder="breed">
                <input type="text" class="form" name="weight" placeholder="weight">
                <input type="text" class="form" name="height" placeholder="height">
                <input type="text" class="form" name="age" placeholder="age">
                <input type="text" class="form" name="fur" placeholder="fur">


                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>


        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if  your petid is 'pa04' it is quite unusal to let people enter the id, it is gerally a hiddenparameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure about your delete method?
Seems to me that it should be

```
    let query = "DELETE FROM pets WHERE pet_id=?";
    let values= [req.body.pet_id];
    connection.query(query, values, function(err,results){
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.redirect("/animals");
    });
```

If this is not a solution, could you just

- `console.log` the generated sql query that failed
- display the sql result for `show create table pets`
- remove all the unecessary html parts

It will help to focus on the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot it really worked for me! @ farvilain

Answer (score 0):

```
    app.post('/delete',(req, res) => {
    let q = "DELETE FROM pets WHERE pet_id=?";
    let dog = [req.body.pet_id];
    connection.query(q,dog,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.redirect("/animals");
});
```

You dont need to mention dog as json a good way to understand and debug your sql queries is to literally type them out on mysql locally ,
the ? used in your query is exactly replaced by the dog variables value and would only make sense to have it as a string or int.